# How to set up Appdynamics Environment

Tags: linux, server-monitoring, appdynamics

I am trying to install Appdynamics APM tool. It has three components :

```
1. Appdynamics Controller
2. Application Server Agent
3. Machine Agent
```

I have few queries:

```
1.How to install all the three? 
2.What are the roles of all of three ? 
3.DO i need to configure all of three again and again for each application
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place for you to get this question answered would be on the AppDynamics community discussion boards. Here's a link for you... http://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Forums-Community-AppDynamics/ct-p/Discussions

The AppDynamics documentation site is also a great resource and you don't even need a login to access them... http://docs.appdynamics.com/

Comment: What is the difference between standalone machine agent and app agents for java .net etc?

Comment: machine agents help you in monitoring the server (machine) level metrics whereas the app agents help you in monitoring your application specific metrics.

Answer (score 0):

1. Installation instructions for the controller can be found in:
   http://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO14S/Install+the+Controller
   Assuming you are using App Server Agent for Java, installation instructions for that and the machine agent can be found in the above site on the Left Nav table of contents.
2. The controller is the management server, the app server agent monitors the JVM and the machine agent collects system metrics (such as CPU, Memory, Disk & Network).
3. Very minimal configuration is required.

Comment: What is the differenet between standalone machine agent and app agents for java .net etc?

Comment: The standalone machine agent collects system metrics whereas the app agents collect application metrics.

Comment: can I check how many % of my CPU is being utilized and memory is utilized with the appdynamics ?? I know I can monitor the apps but how can I monitor the server level details